# How to extract Universal Analytics data from earlier than 2023?

Tags: universal-analytics, transfer, bigquery

I have been testing online products to extract historical Universal Analytics (UA) data and I'm finding that the two that I have tried have limitations. I am wondering if there is any tool (free preferably) that I can use to extract full historical UA data.

[Supermetrics](https://supermetrics.com/) - 14-day free trial, but doesn't let me get data that is older than 14 days (so this is useless given that UA stopped collecting data in middle of 2023)

[Dataddo](https://www.dataddo.com/) - free trial allows me to extract data starting Jan 2023, but not before

[Analytics Canvas](https://analyticscanvas.com/) - not free, but very useful UA Backup tool that costs $99 per view for 10 million rows

Anybody aware of any tools that would let me get data that's even older (into Bigquery)?

Comment: [Recommendations for tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here, so if the answer below isn't sufficient, consider editing your question to focus on other methods without specifically requesting recommendations for third-party tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google has recently issued instructions to complete this task before the **July 1, 2024** deadline, as access to UA and all associated data will be deleted thereafter.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en#export&zippy=%2Chow-can-i-export-data-from-my-universal-analytics-property

> Starting the week of **July 1, 2024:** You won't be able to access any Universal Analytics properties or the API (not even with read-only access), and all data will be deleted.

You can view the article to export your data [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en#export&zippy=%2Chow-can-i-export-data-from-my-universal-analytics-property).

> - [Export individual reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?sjid=4950974680052115181-AP)
> - Use the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) to export data to Cloud storage and connect to Looker Studio.
> - Install the [Google Sheets add-on for Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)
>   -Google Analytics 360 customers can also [export to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618)